# python appending dictionaries to lists causes keyError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am trying to make a list that adds dictionaries to it.
I have done this many times but can't seem to find out why this happens. It should add the dictionary to the list and continue to the code but returns the error `KeyError: '"id"'`
Here is my code
`raid_damage.append("""{"id":{}, "damage":{}, "taken":{}, "streak":{}}""".format(str(user), str(damage_dealt), str(damage_taken), "1"))`

I have tried using ' in place of " (whilst removing the triple quotes) and using eval() but still the exact same error

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome! In your code you're adding *string representation* of dictionary, not a `dict`.

Comment: If you're trying to append dicts, why don't you just make a dictionary rather than the string: `raid_damage.append({"id":str(user),"damage": ...`

Comment: Awesome, ty both of you. Problem fixed, I just started using {}.format() and thought it would be fine. But guess not. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have curly brackets inside your string, when you're using `format()` you get an error because the `{}` are the special char to input the values given in parameter, the solution is to double them

```
raid_damage.append("""{{"id":{}, "damage":{}, "taken":{}, "streak":{}}}""".format(str(user), str(damage_dealt), str(damage_taken), "1"))
print(raid_damage[0]) # {"id":a, "damage":b, "taken":c, "streak":1}
```

**But** careful, you did not add a `dict` but just a `string` representation of a dict, puttinh a dict would be like

```
raid_damage.append({"id":user, "damage":damage_dealt, "taken":damage_taken, "streak":"1"})
print(raid_damage[0]) # {'id': 'a', 'damage': 'b', 'taken': 'c', 'streak': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! Here is a solution with no ''' '''

raid_damage.append({"id": user, "damage":damage_dealt, "taken":damage_taken, "streak":streak})